# how to annotate (label) on the overlay scatterplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter

Here is my code. I got an error on the 2nd plot label. How to include the labels for both scatterplots which overlay each other. Also how to add a legend to specify the green is "leaf" and red is "fruit".
Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = {'id': ['a','b', 'c', 'd'],
    'x1': [2,3,4,5],
    'y1': [2,6,7,2],
        'x2': [4, 5, 6, 7],
      'y2':[4,6,7,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

ax =df.plot.scatter('x1', 'y1', c='green')
for i, txt in enumerate(df.id):
    ax.annotate(txt, (df.x1.iat[i],df.y1.iat[i]))
ax =plt.scatter(df['x2'],df['y2'],c='red')
for i, txt in enumerate(df.id):
    ax.annotate(txt, (df.x2.iat[i],df.y2.iat[i]))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of `ax = plt.scatter(..)` use `df.plot.scatter(...., ax=ax)` or `ax.scatter(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is when you call `plt.scatter` you have renamed the `ax` variable. While the pandas `df.plot.scatter` does return the matplotlib `Axes` instance the plot was created on, the native matplotlib `plt.scatter` instead returns a `PathCollection` instance. You then try calling `ax.annotate`, but `annotate` is not a valid method for a path collection.

It is safer to create the axes from matplotlib, and then you can control where each plot should be created.

Here, I will assume that you intended to use the two different scatter methods for a reason, and show how you can control which Axes they will appear on.

You don't state exactly where you want each of the scatter plots to appear, so here's a couple of options:

#### 2 seperate figures

Assuming you want the two scatter plots in separate `Figure` instances, you could do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = {'id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      'x1': [2, 3, 4, 5],
      'y1': [2, 6, 7, 2],
      'x2': [4, 5, 6, 7],
      'y2': [4, 6, 7, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
df.plot.scatter('x1', 'y1', c='green', ax=ax1)
for i, txt in enumerate(df.id):
    ax1.annotate(txt, (df.x1.iat[i], df.y1.iat[i]))

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.scatter(df['x2'], df['y2'], c='red')
for i, txt in enumerate(df.id):
    ax2.annotate(txt, (df.x2.iat[i], df.y2.iat[i]))

plt.show()
```

#### 2 subplots on the same figure

Assuming you want 2 subplots on the same figure:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = {'id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      'x1': [2, 3, 4, 5],
      'y1': [2, 6, 7, 2],
      'x2': [4, 5, 6, 7],
      'y2': [4, 6, 7, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

df.plot.scatter('x1', 'y1', c='green', ax=ax1)
for i, txt in enumerate(df.id):
    ax1.annotate(txt, (df.x1.iat[i], df.y1.iat[i]))

ax2.scatter(df['x2'], df['y2'], c='red')
for i, txt in enumerate(df.id):
    ax2.annotate(txt, (df.x2.iat[i], df.y2.iat[i]))

plt.show()
```

#### Both scatter plots in the same Axes

Assuming you want both scatter plots to appear on the same subplot you could:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = {'id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      'x1': [2, 3, 4, 5],
      'y1': [2, 6, 7, 2],
      'x2': [4, 5, 6, 7],
      'y2': [4, 6, 7, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot.scatter('x1', 'y1', c='green', ax=ax)
for i, txt in enumerate(df.id):
    ax.annotate(txt, (df.x1.iat[i], df.y1.iat[i]))

ax.scatter(df['x2'], df['y2'], c='red')
for i, txt in enumerate(df.id):
    ax.annotate(txt, (df.x2.iat[i], df.y2.iat[i]))

plt.show()
```

#### Legend

And finally, to answer your question about labelling the colours. You can assign a `label` to each scatterplot instance, e.g.:

```
df.plot.scatter('x1', 'y1', c='green', ax=ax, label='leaf')
ax.scatter(df['x2'], df['y2'], c='red', label='fruit')
```

and the produce a legend on the given Axes with:

```
ax.legend()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The reason I was doing two different scatter methods was trying to overlay two scatter plots, which is one of your methods "both scatter plots in the same axes". Now I much better understand it. Greatly appreciated!